# Remove all rows where length of string is more than n

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `m` and I want to remove all the rows where the `f_name` column has an entry greater than 3. I assume I can use something similar to

```
m <- m[-grep("nchar(m$f_name)>3", m$f_name]
```

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi I'm not sure that edits that trivial are really necessary.

Comment: You need to reword the question. Judging by your code, you don't want to remove "all the rows where the f_name column has an entry greater than 3." You want to remove rows where the length of the string in f_name is greater than 3.

Comment: @joran: agree!! but if that will enhance the readability there is no harm in that :)

Comment: A reproducible data set would be helpful for sure here.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi My point, actually, was that slightly indenting the only line of code in the entire question does not, in fact, enhance its readability, and that edits that trivial are generally considered a nuisance, rather than helpful.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To reword your question slightly, you want to retain rows where entries in f_name have length of 3 or less.  So how about:

```
subset(m, nchar(as.character(f_name)) <= 3)
```

Comment: @hadely That got me in a code I was debugging today.  +1 for a warning to a sneaky problem.

Comment: or wrap the conditional in `isTRUE` to eliminate `NA`s

Answer (score 8):

For those looking for a tidyverse approach, you can use `dplyr::filter`:

```
m %>% dplyr::filter(nchar(f_name) > 3)
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
m[!nchar(as.character(m$f_name)) > 3, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The obligatory `data.table` solution:

```
setDT(m)
m[ nchar(f_name) <= 3 ]
```