# Replace all observations whose character string is greater than X

Tags: r

I have some data which looks like:

```
           col1
1:        PFCB 
2: TEVA TEVATV 
3:        PLCE 
4:             
5:   Nasdaq NEI
6:          DE
```

I would like to replace the observations when the number of characters is greater than 5. For example the expected output for the above sample would be:

```
           col1
1:        PFCB 
2: 
3:        PLCE 
4:             
5:   
6:          DE
```

Data:

```
dt <- data.table(col1 = c("PFCB ", "TEVA TEVATV ", "PLCE ", "", 
"Nasdaq NEI", "DE ", "SHPLN ", "", "WMT ", "ADBE ", "HPY ", "NASDAQ PRTS", 
"", "BEBE ", "PPC ", "Updates with additional background information", 
"CLWR ", "SRX ", "Nasdaq ATVI ", "QLTY ", "AMKR ", " AA ", "ED ", 
"", "", "SLE", "RBNF ", "FIC ", "1135 GMT ", "FROM BARRONS 111813 ", 
"Nasdaq DEIX ", "", "", "Updates throughout with CEO comments details on results", 
"Adds news on Qualcomm F5 Networks Semitool and Celadon Group updates stock prices ", 
"BUSINESS WIRE ", "CXW ", "HOTT ", "BAYNXE", "ICUI ", "", "TI ", 
"BKC ", "", "BUSINESS WIRE ", "B", "", "WBMD ", "AGIX ", "BCSI ", 
"ASGN ", "TUNE ", "", "AIR ", "ETRM ", "MDCO ", "DBTK ", "ROST ", 
"", "Nasdaq SOMX", "PRXL ", "", "SCVL ", "BUSINESS WIRE ", "", 
"OTC Bulletin Board SBNK ", "", "Updates to include details on planned store openings and new stock quote", 
"NASDAQINO ", "", "2008 GMT ", "", "ATRC ", "Updates share prices in the 14th and 15th paragraphs adds Medco statistics on Plavix in the 16th paragraph ", 
"", "", "NASDAQJASN ", "olivergriffindowjonescom OliGGriffin", 
"QCOM ", "ITW ", "NYSE LITB ", "PENN ", "BWA ", "Select Medical ", 
"TQNT ", "SYD ", "IM ", "YHOO ", "TOO ", "", "FO", "", "SMG ", 
"", "Bunge 3Q Profit Drops 86 On Charges As Revenue Rises published at 659 am EDT mischaracterized comments on the companys outlook A corrected story follows", 
"GSOL ", "TGT ", "URI ", "", "PX "))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all rows where length of string is more than n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640377/remove-all-rows-where-length-of-string-is-more-than-n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nchar()` is the function you want:

```
require(data.table)
dt[ nchar(col1) > 5, col1 := '' ]
```